# EXTRACTING VALUES BETWEEN CARET SIGN IN ORACLE

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to extract the values between a caret sign in oracle

value of the field

```
AAA_0^%CELEBRTE%^S~AAA_2^TOP^S~simpLE^True^S~AAA1^NICE^S~
```

output

```
^%CELEBRTE% TOP True NICE
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: regexp_substr would be a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_replace('AAA_0^%CELEBRTE%^S~AAA_2^TOP^S~simpLE^True^S~AAA1^NICE^S~'
  2                      , '^[^^]*\^([^^]*)\^[^^]*\^([^^]*)\^[^^]*\^([^^]*)\^[^^]*\^([^^]*)\^.*'
  3                      , '\1 \2 \3 \4' ) rr
  4    FROM dual;

RR
------------------------
%CELEBRTE% TOP True NICE
```

It clearly assumes that you'll only have 4 items to extract from your data.

I'm no regexp guru, and as an exercise for myself I solved this with what I consider to be a brute force method.  I can see a repeating pattern of groups to extract each string, but in my research on this it seems there's no way to do a "repeating backreference" that automatically creates new capture groups.  If anyone else knows a way to do that, I'd welcome the input.

A couple of handy resources on regular expressions:

[A regular expression tester](https://regex101.com/)

[A basic tutorial](https://regexone.com/)